# Хранение изображений в директории отдельного блока

Tags: gulp, препроцессор, бэм

При сборке проекта на gulp использую следующую структуру файлов

```
|--blocks
   |--block.pug
   |--block.scss
   |--block.js
```

Для каждого самостоятельного блока на сайте создаю директорию, куда складываю все файлы относящиеся к нему. Но теперь подумал, а почему бы не складывать туда изображения относящиеся к этому блоку. Это ведь очень удобно, вместо того чтобы складывать все изображения в общую папку, а потом копаться в ней.

К примеру создаю директорию для блока `logo`, помещаю в неё изображение логотипа, и создаю в ней файл `.pug` в котором допустим описываю `mixin`. А затем просто использую этот блок где угодно. Хоть в футере, хоть на странице "о нас", хоть на странице справки и т.д. Хотелось бы выслушать ваше мнение по этому поводу? Стоит ли так делать, или лучше по старинке все изображения складывать в общую папку?

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы и ДА.
В [методологии BEM](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/filestructure/) сказано - блоки важнее типов файлов (хотя типовая структура там тоже имеется).
Gulp-ом можно обработать все изображения сразу, например [gulp-imagemin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-imagemin)
Собрать все картинки из всех подпапок с компонентами можно так:

```
gulp.task('images', () =>
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.jpg','src/**/*.jpeg','src/**/*.png','src/**/*.gif','src/**/*.svg'])
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'))
);
```

запустить таск можно командой из консоли:

```
gulp images
```

В итоге у нас получится свалка из всех картинок в папке build/images/ которую можно спокойно заливать на хостинг. Серверу уже всё равно из какой папки вставлять картинки в страницу

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Рад что Вы поддержали моё видение. Ну я SVG не копирую, а генерирую из них спрайт одним файлом, который потом отправляется в build. А касаемо сбора изображений, то я использую синтаксис короче:  `gulp.src("src/modules/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}")`

Comment: Мой [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/VladG0r/clean_template/blob/master/gulpfile.js) на всякий, может что пригодится.